# mysql> yaml > Azure Container Apps> translate Command and args from docker compose

Tags: mysql, docker-compose, yaml, azure-container-apps

I am deploying the offical mySQL 5.7 to Azure Container Apps. I have the image / container running. I have translated a docker-compose file to yaml. I have problem translating the "command" node

in docker Compose I have

```
command: --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci
```

In the yaml file i have tried

```
command:
    - --character-set-server=utf8mb4 
    - --collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci
```

and

```
command:
    - --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci
```

If I use any of them the container crashes as start up.

Any idea on how to specify those two commands in yaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In kubernetes, which Azure Container Apps is based on, `command` is `ENTRYPOINT`/`entrypoint` in docker/docker compose. `args` is `CMD`/`command` docker/docker compose

so try:

```yaml
args:
  - --character-set-server=utf8mb4 
  - --collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci
```